# How can I subscribe Java program as a consumer in Activemq?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I want to implement `Pub/Sub` domain in project.Basically I am not a java developer,using google help.I read this [Link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bncdx.html).
I started to implement following structure.
[image]

I wrote Java Application name as `MessageConsumer.java` for receiving messages from AMQ broker and placed in Webserver(Apache Tomcat).

MessageConsumercode:

```
 package PackageName;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.jms.*;
 import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
 public class Consumer extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
//creating connectionfactory object for way
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61617");
//establishing the connection b/w this Application and Activemq
Connection connection=connectionFactory.createConnection();
Session session=connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Topic queue=session.createTopic("MessageTesting");
javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(queue);
//fetching queues from Activemq
MessageListener listener = new MyListener();
consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
connection.start();
}
catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
}
}
```

}

Separatly I wrote another Java Application for processing messages(MyListener.java).

MyListener.java code :

```
package PackageName;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.jms.*;
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    TextMessage msg1=(TextMessage)msg;
    //just for your understanding I mention dummy code
    //System.out.println(msg1.getText());
    MyListener ml=new MyListener();
    try {

      ml.executeHttp("http://localhost:8080/ExecutableFileProcess/ClassName");
        System.out.println(msg1.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Both Java Applications are in webserver(Apache Tomcat).so far we are following in the following way.

1. Before sending messages to Topic,we are triggering MessageConsumer.java through HTTP on browser.

Right know, what we are trying.Initially we don't want to trigger `MessageConsumer.java`.

Means,Assume `MessageConsumer.java` is in Webserver. Initially If AMQ get message from anywhere, our MessageConsumer.java should be process their own logic.

I hope, you guys understand what We are trying.

I never work on `Apache Camel`, can you explain clearly.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 10):

why you want to trigger `MessageConsumer`.java manually as invocation of `Subscriber` is the resposibility of ActiveMQ in your case.

From your topic publish your message to  ActiveMQ server and all the subscribers who subscribed to that topic will get your message without manually triggering it.

refer this as your initial POC `http://activemq.apache.org/hello-world.html`.

You can use below java code for subscribing for topic for **client2** and **client3**

```
import javax.jms.*;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class consumer {
    // URL of the JMS server
    private static String url = ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL;

    // Name of the topic from which we will receive messages from = " testt"

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {
        // Getting JMS connection from the server

        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(url);
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        connection.start();

        Session session = connection.createSession(false,
                Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        Topic topic = session.createTopic("testt");

        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);

        MessageListener listner = new MessageListener() {
            public void onMessage(Message message) {
                try {
                    if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
                        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
                        System.out.println("Received message"
                                + textMessage.getText() + "'");
                    }
                } catch (JMSException e) {
                    System.out.println("Caught:" + e);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        consumer.setMessageListener(listner);

        try {
              System.in.read();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    connection.close();

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you check Apache Camel?
http://camel.apache.org/

You can define routes with camel to publish and subscribe to topics on a broker from java code (integration with spring beans for instance). There are many examples including interaction with an activemq message broker.

Comment: I never use `Apache Camel Api`. I wrote java Application name as MessageConsumer.java for receiving messages from AMQ using `onMessage()`. If you want to see my code I will post. can you help me,Using `Apache Camel` How will I subscribe in AMQ without trigger through HTTP.